# Divide two String into substrings and pair them

Tags: java, string, dictionary, substring

I am looking for interesting solutions for this problem :

```
String key = "1;2;3;4";
String value = "Value1;Value2;Value whitespace;"
```

Now ';' devides each value from another. The same symbol ';' devides the keys also.

Now I want to end up with :

```
{"1" : "Value1", "2" : "Value2", "3" : "Value whitespace", "4" : null}
```

Of course if the values were more then the keys then the null should be no the left side of the pair (null: "Value5").

I made a pretty complecated solution to this problem using char arrays but is one big FOR with many cases and stuff.(it is O(n)). So I am curious to see a regex or substring solution or something that not includes big loop.

EDIT: 
Mine solution :

```
private List<ExampleObject> getExampleObjects(String key , String value) {
    // s
    if (key  == null || value == null) {
        return new ArrayList<ExampleObject>();
    }

    List<ExampleObject> exampleObjects = new ArrayList<ExampleObject>();

    char[] keyToCharArray = key.toCharArray();
    char[] valueToCharArray = value.toCharArray();

    StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();

    boolean nameCompleted = false;
    boolean valueCompleted = false;

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < keyToCharArray.length || j < valueToCharArray.length;) {
        if (!nameCompleted) {
            char a = ' ';
            try{
                 a = keyToCharArray[i];
            } catch(Exception e){
                 a = ';';
                // throw : VALES and key  not match. More key  then value
                //throw(e);
            }

            if (a == ';' ) {
                nameCompleted = true;
            } else if (!(i + 1 < keyToCharArray.length)){
                name.append(a);
                nameCompleted = true;
            }   else {
                name.append(a);

            }
            i++;
        }
        if (!valueCompleted) {

            char a = ' ';
            try{
                 a = valueToCharArray[j];
            } catch(Exception e){
                 a = ';';
                // throw : VALES and key  not match. More value then key 
                //throw(e);
            }

            if (a == ';') {
                valueCompleted = true;
            } else if(!(j + 1 < valueToCharArray.length)) {
                value.append(a);
                valueCompleted = true;
            } else {
                value.append(a);
            }
            j++;
        }
        if (nameCompleted && valueCompleted) {
            exampleObjects.add(new ExampleObject(name.toString(), value.toString()));
            name.setLength(0);
            value.setLength(0);
            nameCompleted = false;
            valueCompleted = false;
        }
    }
    return exampleObjects;
}
```

Where *ExampleObject.class* has fields *key* and *value*.

Comment: Sorry, but we expect you to provide some code; not only requirements. You know, writing down a for loop that used indexOf and substring operations wouldnt be too hard; or simply spliting on ; should also work nicely.

Comment: What is the data structure you want this to be in the end? If you have several values mapped to `null` then it's not a `Map`. Generally speaking, it's just a matter of splitting the strings and looping through the resulting arrays, but it depends on the result you wish to have.

Comment: Well Map would have been okay. I was more curious about the regex because I am not good at writing solutions including regex so just wanted to see how it would look like.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to do this without some kind of loop.  But if it turns out that it _is_ possible, it could only be with the most convoluted and nasty code.  I can't help thinking that this question would be more suited to the programming code golf site.

Comment: OK, so your source code creates a list of pairs, it seems. That's a legitimate choice. Are you aware of the method `split` in `String`?

Comment: I am aware of course. I am not here because I can not do it. I am here to see different solutions and interesting thoughts and give some good ppl some ups.

Comment: @GhostCat there you have the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've come up with a solution to your problem:

**Output**

```
{"1" : "Value1", "2" : "Value2", "3" : "Value whitespace", "4" : "null"}
```

**Code**

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String key = "1;2;3;4";
        String value = "Value1;Value2;Value whitespace;";

        String[] keyArr = key.split(";");
        String[] valueArr = value.split(";");

        String finalJSON = "{";
        for(int i=0; i<(keyArr.length > valueArr.length ? keyArr.length : valueArr.length); i++) {

            try {
                finalJSON += "\"" + keyArr[i] + "\"";
            }
            catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                finalJSON += "\"null\"";
            }

            finalJSON += " : ";

            try {
                finalJSON += "\"" + valueArr[i] + "\"";
            }
            catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                finalJSON += "\"null\"";
            }
            if(i!=(keyArr.length > valueArr.length ? keyArr.length : valueArr.length) - 1) 
                finalJSON += ", ";
        }
        finalJSON += "}";

        System.out.println(finalJSON);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Java 8:

```
String key = "1;2;3;4";
String value = "Value1;Value2;Value whitespace;";
String[] keys = key.split(";", -2);
String[] values = value.split(";", -2);

Map<String, String> result = IntStream.range(0, keys.length).mapToObj(i->i).collect(Collectors.toMap(i->keys[i], i-> values[i]));
result.entrySet().forEach(e->result.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue().length()==0 ? null : e.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Another - slightly more elegant Java8 and Generic as possible.

```
/**
 * General pair of items.
 *
 * @param <P> - Type of the first item in the pair.
 * @param <Q> - Type of the second item.
 */
static class Pair<P, Q> {
    final P p;
    final Q q;

    public Pair(P p, Q q) {
        this.p = p;
        this.q = q;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + p + "," + q + "}";
    }
}

/**
 * Gets the `n`th item is present in the array - otherwise returns null.
 *
 * @param a   - The array
 * @param n   - Which one in the array we want.
 * @param <T> - The type of the array entries.
 * @return - The `n`th entry in the array or null if not present.
 */
private static <T> T n(T[] a, int n) {
    return n < a.length ? a[n] : null;
}

/**
 * Pairs up each element in the arrays.
 *
 * @param <P> - The type of the elements in the `P` array.
 * @param <Q> - The type of the elements in the `Q` array.
 * @param ps  - The `P` array.
 * @param qs  - The `Q` array.
 * @return A list of `Pair`s of each element.
 */
static <P, Q> List pairUp(P[] ps, Q[] qs) {
    return IntStream.range(0, Math.max(ps.length, qs.length))
            .mapToObj(i -> new Pair<>(n(ps, i), n(qs, i)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

/**
 * Splits the two strings on a separator and returns a list of Pairs of the corresponding items.
 *
 * @param a         - The first string.
 * @param b         - The second string.
 * @param separator - The separator.
 * @return - A List of Paired up entries from `a` and `b`.
 */
private static List<Pair<String, String>> fold(String a, String b, String separator) {
    return pairUp(a.split(separator, -1), b.split(separator, -1));
}

public void test() {
    System.out.println(fold("1;2;3;4", "Value1;Value2;Value whitespace", ";"));
}
```

Comment: Nice ! Looks legit

Answer (score 1):

Try the following: (if you want to print a String as you said)

1. Split the two Strings into Arrays using `String#split()`
2. Create counters for the `value[]` and the `key[]`
3. Create a `boolean` to indicate if a key or a value gets appended
4. Use a `StringBuilder` and loop through the length of the key[]
5. Append stuff
6. Return a new `String` using `StringBuilder#append()`

Done. Try it before checking out the solution!

StringBuilder: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html
String: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

My solution for printing out the String:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String key = "1;2;3;4";
    String value = "Value1;Value2;Value whitespace";

    String[] keys = key.split(";");
    String[] values = value.split(";");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("{");
    boolean isKey = true;
    int keyCount = 0;
    int valueCount = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
        sb.append("\"");

        if(isKey) {
            sb.append(keys[keyCount]).append("\" : ");
            keyCount++;
        } else {
            sb.append(values[valueCount]).append("\", ");
            valueCount++;
        }
        isKey = !isKey;
    }

    sb.append("}");
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A different point of view: don't do such things "manually".

What I mean is: instead of doing all "low level" operations yourself; you should abstract.

First, transform your key value strings into a **Map**. Like:

```
String keys[] = keyString.split(";");
String values[] = valueString.split(";);

... probably some consistency checks that arrays have same length; and  no nulls in keys

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i=0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  map.put(keys[i], values[i]);
}
```

then finally, use some existing JSON library to simply generate a JSON representation based on that map.

In other words: unless you are talking about lists with millions of entries; do not worry about performance. Instead, worry about good abstractions, not re-inventing the wheel and code readability.

But if you really have to worry about performance, or memory aspects, then simply split into arrays, and then use those two arrays as input to some function that uses a StringBuilder to build the required output string.